# Verify that file exists on remote machine

Tags: python, windows, cmd, remote-access

I am trying to check if the file that I copied to remote machine is really exists there (actually if copied successfully)

I know about `os.path.exists` and I wrote command to run bat file on remote machine:

```
def run_cmd(ip):
    cmd = r"C:\path\PsExec.exe \\" + ip + " -u " \
          r"User\User -p password -i -h C:\my_bat_file.bat"
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False)
```

But I can't join it into one structure.

Is it possible to join it into one command? And receive True or False response?

Any suggestions are welcome!!!

Sorry for silly question.

Thank you in advance!!!

PS. I gave the command like example.

My aim is to verify by command (os.path.exists maybe) that the specific file is located on remote machine. I have all the access to this machine (ip, username, pass, it is my virtual machine and I use it for tests)

And I asked maybe it is possible to execute using the command from above (using PsExec.exe)

Comment: Is your networking configured such that you could use `os.path.exists('//' + ip + '/C$/my_bat_file.bat')`?

Comment: Emm, no, I think not.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. batch can't run python commands directly - it needs Python installed on server and run it as `python -c "some command"` - but it would be simpler to use normal command in Windows shell to test it - even `dir filename`

Comment: Erm, yes, I think likely.  If you know the UN PW of an admin user on the system you should be able to check the admin share path, unless you guys have disabled these, which isn't actually a great practice..  You could use WMIC or powershell to get the info as well.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I described my problem not clear enough. Updated the question,